# Import a package in Python and got error: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a biologist trying to analyse some of my data. To do that I am trying out a new segmentation approach in Python. I have basic skills in coding and while I was trying out a tutorial, well, I got stuck at the very first step: importing packages.

When I try to import the aforementioned package, I get this message:

```
Python(94548,0x1044b7dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x143e20d20: pointer being freed was not allocated
Python(94548,0x1044b7dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I do not know how to solve this problem.

I followed step by step the guide to download this package: I got Tensorflow 1.15, installed a GCC compiler via homebrew, the package (stardist). But then when I `import stardist` I get this error.

I am working with a macOS 10.15.3 and I run Python 3.7.5. If you can give a clue how to solve this problem, it would be great!

Cheers,
Lucrezia

Comment: How did you install TensorFlow and stardist?

Comment: I used pip in virtualenv for both